# UIA calls with plain JavaScript, don't know how to access DOM-Tree

Tags: javascript, ios, calabash-ios, uia

I'm currently trying to automate an iOs App, which has an SFSafariViewController in it, where I would like to click on a textfield, which has an ID in HTML and also has an AccessibilityIdentifier from the App. 
My question now is how to write the right uia-command, because a normal tap_mark or touch is not helping, because the AccessibilityIdentifier are not found because of the SFSafariViewController. 
My uia command looks like this right now:
`uia("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().document.getElementById('Identifier').click()")`

This is the error I get when I execute the command:

```
RuntimeError: uia action failed because: Input:
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().document.getElementById('Identifier').click(). 
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'UIATarget.localTarget().
frontMostApp().document.getElementById')  eval code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIWebView` for web element but `SFSafariViewController` is not yet supported by Calabash [see this](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/861):

```
touch "UIWebView css:'#Identifier'"
```

And [Xamarin suggests](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/additional-framework-changes/#Safari_Services_Framework_Additions) to replace it with WKWebKit or UIWebView

> Because the SFSafariViewController class is tailored for displaying a single page of web content, you should consider using it to replace any WKWebKit or UIWebView controls within your existing Xamarin.iOS apps.

Comment: I'll try it out and will come back to you if it's working or not!

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't have a UIWebView available, so the Identifier is not found.

Comment: @Buzz seems like calabash doesn't support it yet see my updated answer